# How does FileProvider choose/differentiate provider paths in provider_path.xml?

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-storage

I got to use FileProvider in order to install an apk. Everything works well now but I don't really understand the behaviour FileProvider follows in order to choose the correct path defined inside the *provider_paths.xml*. Here's my code:

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

**main_activity.java**

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File apk = new File("/sdcard/example.apk");
        String fileType = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apk), fileType);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    } else {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
        File apk = new File(directory, "example.apk");
        Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, valoresGenerales.appContext.getPackageName() + ".provider", apk);
        String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(apk.getName()));
        intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, type);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }

    startActivity(intent);
```

**provider_paths.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <files-path name="files_path"  path="Download"/>
</paths>
```

What does make FileProvider choose between **external_path** or **files_path** (or whatever defined in the file) depends on?